# Advice about using Windows 10 OS on a laptop?

Tags: installation, windows-10, hardware, system-requirements

I would like to ask,(I apologize if the question is not for here) whether it will be a good idea to stick with Windows 10 on my laptop or replace it with Windows 10. I read the requirements for Windows 10, I think that my laptop meets them, but in my opinion the software runs a little bit slowly. Here are the hardware specifications:

```
Processor: Intel® Pentium® Processor N4200
RAM : 4GB
```

I would like to ask for your opinion.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not only this question is off-topic. It also asks if you want _to stick with Windows 10 on my laptop or replace it with Windows 10_. Isn't that the same?

Answer (score 0):

This configuration is enough you will get accepted performance